# Mongoose - Validate array of different subdocuments types

Tags: mongodb, validation, mongoose, mongoose-schema, subdocument

I have a schema which has an array of different sub document types.
Below schema is just an example:

VehicleSchema:

```
let BikeSchema = new Schema({
  title       : { type: String, required: [true, 'title is required'] },
  type        : { type: String, required: true, default: "bike" },
  tyres       : { type: Number, required: true, min: 2}
});

let TruckSchema = new Schema({
  title       : { type: String, required: [true, 'title is required'] },
  type        : { type: String, required: true, default: "truck" },
  tyres       : { type: Number, required: true, min: 4},
  doors       : { type: Number, required: true}
});

let VehicleSchema = new Schema({
  name: {type:String, required: [true, 'name is required']},
  vehiclesSelected: [BikeSchema, TruckSchema],
});

Below is the json that I need to validate:
vehicle = {
  "name": 'abc',
  "vehiclesSelected": [
    {"type": "truck", doors: 2},
    {"type": "bike", tyres: 3},
    {"type": "bike"}
  ]
}
```

Now I need to validate the "vehiclesSelected" array based on the 'type' passed in the JSON. Can someone tell me how can I validate an 
array of subdocuments based on a particular field (in this case 'type')?

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: I am also running into this same issue, looking forward for someone to help me out also. Cheers

Comment: If you manage to find a solution, please let me know.

Comment: vehiclesSelected: [BikeSchema, TruckSchema] --> Can you do this? Is it supported in the latest version of Mongoose?

Answer (score 2):

You can make use of Mongoose's discriminator() function.

In your case, what you can do is:

```html
let BikeSchema = new Schema({
  title       : { type: String, required: [true, 'title is required'] },
  tyres       : { type: Number, required: true, min: 2}
});

let TruckSchema = new Schema({
  title       : { type: String, required: [true, 'title is required'] },
  tyres       : { type: Number, required: true, min: 4},
  doors       : { type: Number, required: true}
});

let typeVehicleSchema = new Schema({},
discriminatorKey: 'type', _id: false})

let VehicleSchema = new Schema({
  name: {type:String, required: [true, 'name is required']},
  vehiclesSelected: [typeVehicleSChema],
});

VehicleSchema.path('vehiclesSelected').discriminator('truck', new Schema(TruckSchema))
VehicleSchema.path('vehiclesSelected').discriminator('bike', new Schema(BikeSchema))
```

That way, depending on vehicle type, your schema will validate with the appropriate subType, both inheriting the parent schema (in this case, the typeVehicleSchema), based on the 'type' passed in.